# How can I access dockerfile location within a shell script from outside the docker?

Tags: shell, docker

-I am writing a shell script to check if file exists and is non zero or not. The script is basic though but the challenge here is I want to check the files contained inside a docker. How can I access a docker file location within a script running from outside the docker.
-I am using an array which takes file locations as values for eg :

```
array=(/u01/FDT/FDT_Inbox/MAINFRAME_FILES/DC_NETWORK_CONFIG/sample.txt /u01/FDT/FDT_Inbox/MAINFRAME_FILES/DC_NETWORK_CONFIG/abc.txt)
```

and a for loop for every index i of the array to check if the file exists.

Comment: Host processes can't directly read or write files in containers or images.  You'd need to arrange for this script to run inside a container somehow.  What's the goal of the script; what happens if the files aren't there?

Comment: thanks David. And if the files aren't there in the container, it will throw an alert which can be handled. Also, I am able to run the script inside the container and its working fine but my aim is to run it outside the container on my host and just access the dockerfile locations within the script.